# Using mapstruct to get inner object from outer object

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have an object that looks like this:

```
public class Aggregator {

private Header header;
private Second second;

}
```

And I want to map from Aggregator to Header but I can't use void methods
Mapstruct version is 1.3

How can I achieve that goal?

Edit:

I'm trying to map the business entity "Aggregator" to the DTO entity "HeaderDTO"

I'm trying to achieve that by creating an abstract class with the annotation: @Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
and the method:
"public abstract HeaderDTO toDTO(Aggregator aggregator);"

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public abstract class AggregatorMapper {


public abstract HeaderDTO toDTO(Aggregator aggregator);

}
```

Comment: What do you mean with you want to map from Aggregator to Header? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Filip
Thanks for answering
I created an abstract class with annotation: @Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
and the method:
public abstract HeaderDTO toDTO(Aggregator aggregator);

So the goal is to get the Header from aggregator and map it to headerDTO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapStruct allows you to map the entire target object to a particular source reference.

e.g.

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public abstract class AggregatorMapper {

    @Mapping(target = ".", source = "header"
    public abstract HeaderDTO toDTO(Aggregator aggregator);

}
```